# Hacking rails.vim to work with Padrino

Tags: ruby, vim, padrino

I recently cloned rails.vim (vim-rails) hoping to modify it to work with Padrino projects.

Currently I'm trying to get the `Rcontroller` command to look not only in app/controllers (perfect for rails) but also in any folder in the project that has a sub-folder called 'controllers'. So when I type Rcontroller in command-mode and hit tab, I should be able to tab through `admin/controllers/base.rb`, `admin/controllers/accounts.rb`, `app/controllers/events.rb` etc. This will let users of the plugin to jump to controllers in a 'subapp' of a Padrino application. e.g. `PADRINO_ROOT/admin`

The current `controllerList` function seems to handle this autocompletion and here's what I have so far (only slightly modified from the original source)

```
function! s:controllerList(A,L,P)
  let con = padrino#app().relglob("*/controllers/","**/*",".rb") 
  call map(con,'s:sub(v:val,"_controller$","")')
  return s:autocamelize(con,a:A)  
endfunction
```

I added the wildcard before the controllers directory but this gives results like

- `Rcontroller ers/base`
- `Rcontroller ers/sessions`
- `Rcontroller s/events`

for the last one it looks like there is somethings weird going on with string lengths or overlap...

Ideally I'd like to get it to the point where typing `Rcontroller admin<TAB>` should result in autocompletion to `Rcontroller admin/controllers/accounts.rb`. Likewise, `Rcontroller app<TAB>` should result in `Rcontroller app/controllers/events.rb`

The code for the `viewList` function has something similar to this and its code is as follows:

```
 function! s:viewList(A,L,P)
   let c = s:controller(1)
   let top = padrino#app().relglob("app/views/",s:fuzzyglob(a:A))
   call filter(top,'v:val !~# "\\~$"')
   if c != '' && a:A !~ '/'
     let local = padrino#app().relglob("app/views/".c."/","*.*[^~]")
     return s:completion_filter(local+top,a:A)
   endif
   return s:completion_filter(top,a:A)
 endfunction
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: and you checked this too? https://github.com/gerardc/vim-padrino - it is not mature yet, but (maybe) can help...

Comment: That's actually my clone of rails.vim! :)

Comment: hello.... are you still there ? :)

Comment: > That's actually my clone of rails.vim! -- So...meta :)

Comment: @gcahill - did my answer help you solve your problem at all? If it did - would you accept my answer please? :) it'll also help improve your accept-rate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the full path to look like this:

```
**/controllers/**/*.rb
```

which globs as "look under any directory for a directory called controllers, then look anywhere under that for a file ending in .rb"

Looking at other usages of "relglob", I can only guess at how it's supposed to work, but my guess is:

- first param is "which directory to start looking in"
- second param is "how to multiply out the directories from there"
- third param is "actual files that will match"

based on this assumption, my guess would be to use:

```
padrino#app().relglob("app/","**/controllers/**/*",".rb")
```

Caveat: this is based on my understanding of glob, not of vim or relglob
adjust as per actual usage.

Note: have added "app/" in the assumption that you're unlikely to want to be tabbing through any controllers under vendor/plugin or vendor/gems. This may not be the case, in which case, feel free to change it to "."